# Javascript - Remove string variable after 3 seconds

Tags: javascript

I couldn't find anything that similar to this issue anywhere else so I've opened up a new post. I have a bunch of alerts I want to display at a certain time. So i'm using an alert string variable and just setting that variable every time I want the text to change.

E.g alert = 'You died';

I want to clear the alert variable every 3 seconds I'm not sure how to go about that.

My best guess is

```
var alert(function(){timer()},3000);
```

I'm not sure

Comment: Do you mean you want an alert to fire after 3 seconds?

Comment: Where did you find that syntax?

Comment: every 3 seconds I want the alert to display no string so after 3 seconds alert = '';

Answer (score 0):

If by "alert" you mean the `alert` function, you can't do it. Only the user can close the alert.

What you can do instead is show an element on the page, then remove it after three seconds.

Very rough example:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = "Message for user (can include HTML markup)";
document.body.appendChild(div);
setTimeout(function() {
    div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
}, 3000);
```

Of course, you'll want to do something more interesting with the element than just put it at the bottom of the document body (perhaps you'd make it an absolutely-positioned `div` with an iframe backdrop to grey-out and disable the remainder of the page), but that's just a refinement of the basic task.